# Pi bluetooth audio: can't get LMS squeezelite audio to BT

Tags: audio, bluetooth, pi-3b+, media-server

I have a Pi 3B+ running Raspbian Stretch. I want to send audio via the built-in BT to a Logitech Audio Adapter which feeds my stereo. I can do this from the command line via either aplay or mpg123 so some hw/sw works ok.

I have installed Logitech Media Server (with lots of help from [Gerrelt](http://www.gerrelt.nl/RaspberryPi/wordpress/tutorial-installing-squeezelite-player-on-raspbian/#Installing_Squeezelite)),  and that works with both local audio files as well as internet radio, but the output goes to the 3.5mm jack. I've done lots of searching, trial and error, etc., but I can't get the audio from LMS to the built-in BT.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks...

Comment: +1 for a good question. I wish I could offer an answer, but there are several un-answered questions here on Bluetooth. It seems there are mixed results using RPi's built-in Bluetooth: some seem to have few problems, others (me for example) have no success at all. There is [one solution that seems to have some promise](https://youness.net/raspberry-pi/how-to-connect-bluetooth-headset-or-speaker-to-raspberry-pi-3#comment-39672), but I've not had time to try it... it may help you?

Answer (score 1):

PiCorePlayer to the rescue. For now, I'm using a dedicated 3B+ as music server running [piCorePlayer](https://www.picoreplayer.org/) serving music via BlueTooth to either a BT speaker (UE Boom 2) or Logitech BT audio adapter which feeds my stereo. The BT connection runs in 'beta' mode, so it may not be fully baked yet. I do find that to change speakers, I have to reboot to complete the change.

The music files are on a USB thumb drive plugged into the Pi, almost all compressed. It serves up wav, mp3, and m4a files. I haven't tried others.

I'm running with a (wired) ethernet connection for now.

pCP uses Logitech Media Server as the interface which indexes local music files and serves up internet radio. The interface can be an app (Squeezer on Android for me) or web pages served up on the Pi by pCP. It would be great if I could change speakers (and reboot as necessary) from the app.

For now, it's just what I want, working well.

Minor correction - to switch speakers, a reboot isn't necessary, ***restarting*** Squeezelite finishes the job.